# How to navigate gmail app info programmatically in android

Tags: android, google-maps

[How to navigate to Google map app info settings screen in android programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23219249/how-to-navigate-to-google-map-app-info-settings-screen-in-android-programmatical)

please see this above link.
This is my exact requirement, how to solve this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
in 2.2 and below, there is no public APIs you can access. But you can still start the InstalledAppDetails activity just as the ManageApplications does.

 // utility method used to start sub activity
 private void startApplicationDetailsActivity() {
     // Create intent to start new activity
     Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
     intent.setClass(this, InstalledAppDetails.class);
     intent.putExtra(APP_PKG_NAME, mCurrentPkgName);
     // start new activity to display extended information
     startActivityForResult(intent, INSTALLED_APP_DETAILS);
 }
Conclusion: you can start the "application info" screen like this i wrote:

private static final String SCHEME = "package";

private static final String APP_PKG_NAME_21 = "com.android.settings.ApplicationPkgName";

private static final String APP_PKG_NAME_22 = "pkg";

private static final String APP_DETAILS_PACKAGE_NAME = "com.android.settings";

private static final String APP_DETAILS_CLASS_NAME = "com.android.settings.InstalledAppDetails";

public static void showInstalledAppDetails(Context context, String packageName) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    final int apiLevel = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if (apiLevel >= 9) { // above 2.3
        intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
        Uri uri = Uri.fromParts(SCHEME, packageName, null);
        intent.setData(uri);
    } else { // below 2.3
        final String appPkgName = (apiLevel == 8 ? APP_PKG_NAME_22
                : APP_PKG_NAME_21);
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setClassName(APP_DETAILS_PACKAGE_NAME,
                APP_DETAILS_CLASS_NAME);
        intent.putExtra(appPkgName, packageName);
    }
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: this code working perfectly other my sample app.but google map only problem

Comment: use APP PACKAGE NAME IN ABOVE FUNCTION to "com.google.android.apps.maps"

Comment: sir. what i need to give INSTALLED_APP_DETAILS